# Jade default content

Tags: pug

I have done the following:

```
mixin article(newTitle)

#title
    if (newTitle)
        newTitle
    else
        block article-block-title
#content
    if block
        block
    else
        block article-block-content

block article-block-title
    Default  title text

block article-block-content
    Default  content text
```

So I can use this on my homepage like

```
+article //Will render the Default article

+article // Should render default title and new content
    p Some more content

+article("New Title") // Should render the new title and the default content

+article("New Title and Content") // Should render a new article
    p Some more content
```

But it's not working. The Default values are never rendered, only the block is. Neither the new title passed in is working. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can override Blocks only by extending templates. You should declare default values directly:

```
mixin article(newTitle)

    #title
        if (newTitle)
            newTitle
        else
            Default title text

    #content
        if block
            block
        else
            p Default content text
```